# Custom orderBy with odata?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata

In an AngularApp, i am getting my data from a WebAPI via OData queries.

All results have a date and an int statuscode. Statuscode can be 1, 2, 3 or 4.

I want to order my results, so all results with statuscode 1, goes to the top of the list. The rest of the results, with code 2, 3 and 4, gets sorted by the data attached to them, and not the statuscode.

Possible?

This is my code as it looks now. It just sorts by the date, and nothing else.

```
return Products.query({ $orderby: 'Date' });
```

Comment: Do you have control over the OData service? In other words, can you add new behavior to the service?

Comment: Yes, i can change it. What are you thinking?

Comment: You cannot pass an arbitrary sorting function to `$orderby`. Anyway, it would be better IMO to define an [OData function](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398351) to perform the sorting, rather than require the client to supply a complex `$orderby` clause. A request to a function bound to the `Products` entity set would look like `GET  http://host/Products/ServiceNamespace.CustomOrderBy`.

Comment: I have a client-side solution for you below.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you want all Products with `StatusCode` of 1 to be treated equally. That is, they are not further sorted by `Date`. If you can relax this requirement a bit and allow all Products to be sorted by `StatusCode` *and* `Date`, there is a straightforward solution:

```
return Products.query({ $orderby: 'StatusCode,Date' });
```

The [`$orderby` query option](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398305) in OData v4 consists of "a comma-separated list of expressions whose primitive result values are used to sort the items". Property names are the most common expressions used to produce sort values.

If you want to reverse the ordering on a particular property, use the `desc` suffix on that property like so:

```
return Products.query({ $orderby: 'StatusCode,Date desc' });
```